How would I go about fixing this gap between the carpet and floor?
I need a few suggestions on how to fix this gap between the floor and carpet. What do y'all think?



Add more tile to reach the wall and replace with a wider threshold.
The  threshold should  the same width as the door frame, if not a bit more.
A 1x6 instead of a 1x4.
